# dbf export cols to csv

Tags: python, dbf

Is it possible to export certain columns from a dbf database. The dbf table that I am trying to export has 150+ columns and I am only interested in 5. I am using the dbf module.

```
db = dbf.Table(dbf_link)
db.open()

dbf.export(db, filename='', fields='', format='csv', header=True)
```

gives me the error "unexpected keyword 'fields'"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When in doubt, check out the code ([latest available here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dbf)).

There is an export method that looks like this:

```
def export(
        table_or_records,
        filename=None,
        field_names=None,
        format='csv',
        header=True,
        dialect='dbf',
        encoding=None,
        ):
```

So you will want something like:

```
dbf.export(db, field_names=['field_1', 'field_2', ..., 'field_n'])
```

where `field_1`, etc., are the actual field names you want.

Comment: I tried that but it comes back with "unexpected keyword 'fields'"

Comment: @Mantis please post code that you created and that gives this error